# Socket.io adding port to url

Tags: sockets, express, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my socket.io server on heroku. I'm serving up my Backbone clientside with a simple express server on port 8080. When I try to do:

```
io.connect('https://test16793.herokuapp.com/');
```

I get:

**GET https://test16793.herokuapp.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1482505848382-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

However, when I just open my index.html file itself, it manages to connect to heroku without a problem. It seems like the port number is being added to the end of the heroku link before it attempts to connect when it's served using express.

Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;` for your app port instead of `8080`.

When you connect to your https://xxxx.herokuapp.com subdomain on heroku on port 443 (which is the port that is used for an https connection when no port is specified), Heroku is probably using a proxy or router to route that incoming connection to the particular port that your node.js server is listening to. In the Heroku infrastructure, they know what actual internal host your server is running on and what actual port number it is running on so they can map a default port request on your subdomain to the actual port/host.

This is done so that browsers can connect to your subdomain directly on the default port without having to know the particulars of your node server installation and so that Heroku can auto-manage your server and likely share hardware with other customers. You are each running on a different port, but sharing the same machine. The ports are managed entirely by Heroku and this is one way that they are able to put multiple customers on the same hardware without each having to specify a custom port in the browser URL (which would be a non-starter for most customers).

So, Heroku is hosting some sort of proxy for your sub-domain that is listening to the default https port. Thus, you don't have to specify the port in the URL. Internally, they route that connection to your actual port on your actual server.

When running on your desktop, there is no such proxy to do this for you so you have to make sure client and server port numbers match.

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757677/i-dont-have-to-specify-a-port-for-heroku-for-my-socket-io-app)